# where does WINE install?

Tags: software-installation, wine, directory

ok, similar questions have been asked, but my specific one is a little different, I think.

when I go to install WINE in Ubuntu, where does it put all WINE's files? I'd like to use a Symbolic Link to redirect the install onto another disk, but I can't run the WINE installer first, because the disk it wants to install to is too small. I can't replace or upgrade this drive. if it installs to a directory like, say, /wine-files/ for example, then I'd like to create this folder first in a external drive, then create a symbolic link to it, so it'll redirect where it's downloading to, hopefully.

Comment: Ubuntu programs don't install like Windows programs into one folder. Some go to lib, some go to bin, etc. As for Windows programs installed in wine, they will be in a sub folder of your home folder.

Answer (score 0):

The base directory will be...

```
/home/$USER/.wine/
```

There will be a dosdevices/ in there with windows styled labels in there (ie. `c`, `d` etc).